Continuity and Surjectivity of Distance-Expanding Functions
Let $K\subseteq \mathbb R$ be non-empty and $f: K\to K$ be continuous such that $$|x-y|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|~\forall x,y\in K.$$ Which of the following statements are true?
$1.$ $f$ need not surjective.
$2.$ $f$ must be surjective if $K = [0,1]$.
$3.$ $f$ is injective and $f^{-1}: f(K)\to K$ is continuous.
$4.$ $f$ is injective, but  $f^{-1}: f(K)\to K$ need not be  continuous.
If $ K = \mathbb{R} $, it can be proved that $ f $ is both one-to-one and onto by showing that the limits of $ f $ as $ x \to \infty $ and $ x \to -\infty $ are $\infty$ and $-\infty$, and then using the intermediate value property to establish surjectivity.
However, how can we show that $ f $ is surjective when $ K = [0, 1] $? Proving injectivity is straightforward since $|x - y| > 0 $ implies $ |f(x) - f(y)| > 0 $?
For the last two options, there is a problem because $ K $ is not necessarily an interval, so we cannot directly apply the inverse function theorem to guarantee the continuity of $ f^{-1} $.
Please help me solve this problem, as the given answer is that statements 1, 2, and 3 are true.

$f$ must not be surjective. For example, take $K=\mathbb{N}$ and $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, n\mapsto n+1$. $f$ is continous since $K=\mathbb{N}$ is a discrete set. We have
$$|f(n)-f(m)|=|n+1 - (m+1)|=|n-m| \ \forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}.$$
But $f$ is not surjective since there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=1$.
To show that $f$ is surjective for $K=[0,1]$, we can observe that $f([0,1])$ must be a compact interval $[a,b] \subseteq [0,1]$ with $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$. Therefore, we know that
$$1=|1-0| \leq |f(1)-f(0)| \leq b - a \leq 1.$$
This implies that $b-a=1$, so $a=0$ and $b=1$ and therefore $f$ is surjective.
For the continuity of $f^{-1}\colon f(K) \to K$ we see that the condition
$$|x-y|\leq |f(x)-f(y)| \ \forall x,y\in K$$
implies that
$$|f^{-1}(u) - f^{-1}(v)| \leq |u-v| \ \forall u,v\in f(K)$$
by taking $x=f^{-1}(u)$ and $y=f^{-1}(v)$. Thus, $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz continous, which implies the continuity of $f^{-1}$.
